# Transfer article to better Physical Review journal

Tags: peer-review, paper-submission, editors

I submitted a paper to *PRA: Rapid Communications*. I was asked to resubmit because my supplemental material was too long and contained material that should be in the main text.

In the meantime, however, I got positive community feedback on the preprint and was reminded of the existence of *PRX: Quantum*. So I wish to transfer my new submission to *PRX: Quantum*.

My expectation is that *PRX: Quantum* will be more selective than *PRA: Rapid Communications*. Would you expect that a direct transfer of my paper from *PRA: Rapid Communications* to *PRX: Quantum* will hurt my chances compared to a direct submission to *PRX: Quantum*?

Remember, the paper has not yet been reviewed and has not been rejected on any substantial ground.

UPDATE: I explained the situation and the paper was transferred to *PRX Quantum* and is under review.

Comment: I didn't know that anyone directly submits a Rapid Communication.

Comment: I'd guess that PRX and PRA have the same editorial standards.

Comment: They have different editorial standards but are part of the same institution.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist PRX and PRA don't have the same editorial standards.  (For one thing, PRX cares about "fancy-ness".)  However, this is "PRX Quantum", which is an entirely new journal - so I guess it is not clear where it will stand.

Answer (score 4):

Write to the editor and ask for a transfer, explaining the situation. The editor will tell you what the preferred action is. Asking for a transfer, rather than withdrawing and resubmitting on your own will not hurt your chances, rather the opposite, as the editor then knows what is going on - and you don't risk to fall under some rule of the manuscript need to only be submitted to one journal at a time. Since both journals are under the same umbrella, they should have no problem at all with this.